# How to implement data access in Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, portable-class-library, system.data

We are investigating the possibility of using Xamarin.Android to build software for internal business devices that run Android.  These devices are locked to a specific internal WiFi network to which we can give access to our databases using network safety.

We have built a successful proof-of-concept app that communicates with our database using the `System.Data` `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` classes.

Now we are trying to build an app closer to the architecture we will use for the final app and so we are trying to separate out the data access from the Xamarin UI app.

We have tried "Portable Class Library" and "Class Library (Android)", both of which do not include `System.Data`.

Are there any issues if we use a standard "Class Library" as it is not mobile specific?